# How to set up and solve simultaneous equations in python

Tags: python, math, numpy

For a fixed integer `n`, I have a set of `2(n-1)` simultaneous equations as follows.

```
M(p) = 1+((n-p-1)/n)*M(n-1) + (2/n)*N(p-1) + ((p-1)/n)*M(p-1)

N(p) = 1+((n-p-1)/n)*M(n-1) + (p/n)*N(p-1)

M(1) = 1+((n-2)/n)*M(n-1) + (2/n)*N(0)

N(0) = 1+((n-1)/n)*M(n-1)
```

`M(p)` is defined for `1 <= p <= n-1`.  `N(p)` is defined for `0 <= p <= n-2`.  Notice also that `p` is just a constant integer in every equation so the whole system is linear.

I have been using Maple but I would like to set these up and solve them in python now, maybe using `numpy.linalg.solve` (or any other better method).  I actually only want the value of `M(n-1)`. For example, when `n=2` the answer should be `M(1) = 4`, I believe.  This is because the equations become

```
M(1) = 1+(2/2)*N(0)
N(0) = 1 + (1/2)*M(1)
```

Therefore

```
M(1)/2 = 1+1
```

and so

```
M(1) = 4.
```

If I want to plug in `n=50`, say, how can you set up this system of simultaneous equations in python so that numpy.linalg.solve can solve them?

**Update**  The answers are great but they use dense solvers where the system of equations is sparse.  Posted follow up to [Using scipy sparse matrices to solve system of equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380899/using-scipy-sparse-matrices-to-solve-system-of-equations) .

Comment: These don't look like linear equations so I don't think you'll be able solve them with a linear algebra solver.

Comment: Can you express those using `*`? I'm having a hard time resolving operator precendence with your implicit multiplies

Comment: @lip1: these are not linear equations. The last term of the `M(p)` contains the product of `p` and `M(p-1)`. This is contrary to the definition of a [linear equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearEquation.html), which requires that each term be a constant or a first-order term.

Comment: @lip1 is correct with his claim of linearity. `p` is a constant for each equation, `M(p-1)` simply refers to the previous element in vector `M`.

Comment: ...which is best seen if you put the constant, i.e. the `1`s on one side and all the rest on the other

Comment: @Eric Added *'s and also some brackets.

Comment: @s.bandara  Yes that's right. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updated: added implementation using scipy.sparse

---

This gives the solution in the order `N_max,...,N_0,M_max,...,M_1`.

The linear system to solve is of the shape `A dot x == const 1-vector`.
`x` is the sought after solution vector.
Here I ordered the equations such that `x` is `N_max,...,N_0,M_max,...,M_1`.
Then I build up the `A`-coefficient matrix from 4 block matrices.

Here's a snapshot for the example case `n=50` showing how you can derive the coefficient matrix and understand the block structure. The coefficient matrix `A` is light blue, the constant right side is orange. The sought after solution vector `x` is here light green and used to label the columns. The first column show from which of the above given eqs. the row (= eq.) has been derived:
[image]

As Jaime suggested, multiplying by `n` improves the code. This is not reflected in the spreadsheet above but has been implemented in the code below:

**Implementation using numpy:**

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as linalg


def solve(n):
    # upper left block
    n_to_M = -2. * np.eye(n-1) 

    # lower left block
    n_to_N = (n * np.eye(n-1)) - np.diag(np.arange(n-2, 0, -1), 1)

    # upper right block
    m_to_M = n_to_N.copy()
    m_to_M[1:, 0] = -np.arange(1, n-1)

    # lower right block
    m_to_N = np.zeros((n-1, n-1))
    m_to_N[:,0] = -np.arange(1,n)

    # build A, combine all blocks
    coeff_mat = np.hstack(
                          (np.vstack((n_to_M, n_to_N)),
                           np.vstack((m_to_M, m_to_N))))

    # const vector, right side of eq.
    const = n * np.ones((2 * (n-1),1))

    return linalg.solve(coeff_mat, const)
```

**Solution using scipy.sparse:**

```
from scipy.sparse import spdiags, lil_matrix, vstack, hstack
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
import numpy as np


def solve(n):
    nrange = np.arange(n)
    diag = np.ones(n-1)

    # upper left block
    n_to_M = spdiags(-2. * diag, 0, n-1, n-1)

    # lower left block
    n_to_N = spdiags([n * diag, -nrange[-1:0:-1]], [0, 1], n-1, n-1)

    # upper right block
    m_to_M = lil_matrix(n_to_N)
    m_to_M[1:, 0] = -nrange[1:-1].reshape((n-2, 1))

    # lower right block
    m_to_N = lil_matrix((n-1, n-1))
    m_to_N[:, 0] = -nrange[1:].reshape((n-1, 1))

    # build A, combine all blocks
    coeff_mat = hstack(
                       (vstack((n_to_M, n_to_N)),
                        vstack((m_to_M, m_to_N))))

    # const vector, right side of eq.
    const = n * np.ones((2 * (n-1),1))

    return spsolve(coeff_mat.tocsr(), const).reshape((-1,1))
```

Example for `n=4`:

```
[[ 7.25      ]
 [ 7.76315789]
 [ 8.10526316]
 [ 9.47368421]   # <<< your result
 [ 9.69736842]
 [ 9.78947368]]
```

Example for `n=10`:

```
[[ 24.778976  ]
 [ 25.85117842]
 [ 26.65015984]
 [ 27.26010007]
 [ 27.73593401]
 [ 28.11441922]
 [ 28.42073207]
 [ 28.67249606]
 [ 28.88229939]
 [ 30.98033266]  # <<< your result
 [ 31.28067182]
 [ 31.44628982]
 [ 31.53365219]
 [ 31.57506477]
 [ 31.58936225]
 [ 31.58770694]
 [ 31.57680467]
 [ 31.560726  ]]
```

Comment: @lip1, please let me know if its actually correct -- it seems to be correct for n=3, but you might be able to check also for n=10 with your Maple code...

Comment: Nice! As I commented in my answer, you can clean up the code a little by multiplying by `n` everywhere to get rid of all the denominators.

Comment: @Jaime, very good suggestion -- that would clean up quite a lot -- I'll update my answer, thanks.

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke  The answer for n=4 should be 180/19 which is 9.473684211. This is also what Jaime gets but isn't what your code gives it seems.

Comment: @lip1, found the error: should be (and is now) `n_to_N = (n * np.eye(n-1)) - np.diag(np.arange(n-2, 0, -1), 1)` but was before `... np.arange(1, n-1)`, the spreadsheet is right but I made this mistake, please check...

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke My system is actually sparse. Maybe http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html is the way to go?

Comment: @lip1, I added an implementation using scipy.sparse... I'm not an expert though, for sure construction of the coefficient matrix can be done faster and/or more efficient using/combining different storage schemes... or maybe building the whole matrix at once. But I guess this doesn't matter cause the bottleneck will anyway be the solver...

Answer (score 4):

Here's an entirely different approach, using `sympy`.  It's not fast, but it allows me to copy the RHS of your equations exactly, limiting the thinking I need to do (always a plus), and gives fractional answers.

```
from sympy import Integer, Symbol, Eq, solve

def build_equations(n):
    ni = n
    n = Integer(n)
    Ms = {p: Symbol("M{}".format(p)) for p in range(ni)}
    Ns = {p: Symbol("N{}".format(p)) for p in range(ni-1)}
    M = lambda i: Ms[int(i)] if i >= 1 else 0
    N = lambda i: Ns[int(i)]

    M_eqs = {}
    M_eqs[1] = Eq(M(1), 1+((n-2)/n)*M(n-1) + (2/n)*N(0))
    for p in range(2, ni):
        M_eqs[p] = Eq(M(p), 1+((n-p-1)/n)*M(n-1) + (2/n)*N(p-1) + ((p-1)/n)*M(p-1))

    N_eqs = {}
    N_eqs[0] = Eq(N(0), 1+((n-1)/n)*M(n-1))
    for p in range(1, ni-1):
        N_eqs[p] = Eq(N(p), 1+((n-p-1)/n)*M(n-1) + (p/n)*N(p-1))

    return M_eqs.values() + N_eqs.values()

def solve_system(n, show=False):

    eqs = build_equations(n)
    sol = solve(eqs)

    if show:
        print 'equations:'
        for eq in sorted(eqs):
            print eq
        print 'solution:'
        for var, val in sorted(sol.items()):
            print var, val, float(val)

    return sol
```

which gives

```
>>> solve_system(2, True)
equations:
M1 == N0 + 1
N0 == M1/2 + 1
solution:
M1 4 4.0
N0 3 3.0
{M1: 4, N0: 3}
>>> solve_system(3, True)
equations:
M1 == M2/3 + 2*N0/3 + 1
M2 == M1/3 + 2*N1/3 + 1
N0 == 2*M2/3 + 1
N1 == M2/3 + N0/3 + 1
solution:
M1 34/5 6.8
M2 33/5 6.6
N0 27/5 5.4
N1 5 5.0
{M2: 33/5, M1: 34/5, N1: 5, N0: 27/5}
```

and

```
>>> solve_system(4, True)
equations:
M1 == M3/2 + N0/2 + 1
M2 == M1/4 + M3/4 + N1/2 + 1
M3 == M2/2 + N2/2 + 1
N0 == 3*M3/4 + 1
N1 == M3/2 + N0/4 + 1
N2 == M3/4 + N1/2 + 1
solution:
M1 186/19 9.78947368421
M2 737/76 9.69736842105
M3 180/19 9.47368421053
N0 154/19 8.10526315789
N1 295/38 7.76315789474
N2 29/4 7.25
{N2: 29/4, N1: 295/38, M1: 186/19, M3: 180/19, N0: 154/19, M2: 737/76}
```

which seems to match the other answers.

Comment: +1) very nice --- maybe you can 'branch out' and use the intermediate EQ-objects to construct numpy-arrays to solve (in addition) numerically

Comment: The problem with the approach (as DSM implies) is that it keeps complete precision which  means it simply doesn't work for n>100 or so.

Answer (score 3):

This is messy, but solves your problem, barring a very probable mistake transcribing the coefficients:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np    
n = 2
# Solution vector is [N[0], N[1], ..., N[n - 2], M[1], M[2], ..., M[n - 1]]
n_pos = lambda p : p
m_pos = lambda p : p + n - 2
A = np.zeros((2 * (n - 1), 2 * (n - 1)))
# p = 0
# N[0] + (1 - n) / n * M[n-1] = 1
A[n_pos(0), n_pos(0)] = 1 # N[0]
A[n_pos(0), m_pos(n - 1)] = (1 - n) / n #M[n - 1]
for p in xrange(1, n - 1) :
    # M[p] + (1 + p - n) /n * M[n - 1] - 2 / n * N[p - 1] +
    #  (1 - p) / n * M[p - 1] = 1
    A[m_pos(p), m_pos(p)] = 1 # M[p]
    A[m_pos(p), m_pos(n - 1)] =  (1 + p - n) / n # M[n - 1]
    A[m_pos(p), n_pos(p - 1)] = -2 / n # N[p - 1]
    if p > 1 :
        A[m_pos(p), m_pos(p - 1)] = (1 - p) / n # M[p - 1]
    # N[p] + (1 + p -n) / n * M[n - 1] - p / n * N[p - 1] = 1
    A[n_pos(p), n_pos(p)] = 1 # N[p]
    A[n_pos(p), m_pos(n - 1)] = (1 + p - n) / n # M[n - 1]
    A[n_pos(p), n_pos(p - 1)] = -p / n # N[p - 1]
if n > 2 :
    # p = n - 1
    # M[n - 1] - 2 / n * N[n - 2] + (2 - n) / n * M[n - 2] = 1
    A[m_pos(n - 1), m_pos(n - 1)] = 1 # M[n - 1]
    A[m_pos(n - 1), n_pos(n - 2)] = -2 / n # N[n - 2]
    A[m_pos(n - 1), m_pos(n - 2)] = (2 - n) / n # M[n - 2]
else :
    # p = 1 
    #M[1] - 2 / n * N[0] = 1
    A[m_pos(n - 1), m_pos(n - 1)] = 1
    A[m_pos(n - 1), n_pos(n - 2)] = -2 / n

X = np.linalg.solve(A, np.ones((2 * (n - 1),)))
```

But it gives a solution of

```
>>> X[-1]
6.5999999999999979
```

for `M(2)` when `n=3`, which is not what you came up with.

Comment: Your exact code (after adding from __future__ import division
import numpy as np) gives me 2.53846153846 (which I don't think is right either) not 6.5999999999999979 . For n = 2 I added a full worked example to the question.

Comment: @lip1 It now solves `n = 2` properly, that's a special case that needs to be treated apart. But my result for `n = 3` is different, although the `A` matrix computed by the program matches with what I get by hand. What equations did you solve to get `M(2) = 147 / 13`?

Comment: My mistake I think. In Maple it is > solve({m2=1+(2/3)*n1+(1/3)*m1, m1=1+(1/3)*m2+(2/3)*n0, n1=1+(1/3)*m2+(1/3)*n0, n0=1+(2/3)*m2}) which gives m2=33/5 which is what you got! In fact I get 6.6 exactly with your code which is even better.

Comment: @lip1 All those assignments I have done with a for loop could be vectorized, but I already got a headache from figuring out the coefficients like this! By the way, if you multiply every equation by `n` things look a little bit less intimidating.